# Affine variety as subset of another affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

I am trying to understand why the following statement is true:

> If $S$ and $S'$ are subsets of $\mathbb{K}[X_1,...,X_n]$ such that
>   $S\subseteq S'$, then $\mathcal{V}(S') \subseteq \mathcal{V}(S)$.

Can someone provide an example of two polynomial sets with their varieties, such that I might understand why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to realize is that intuitively, the vanishing sets $V(S)$ are essentially the embeddings of your polynomials into $n$-dimensional space.

So, for instance, let's take $S=\{Y-2X\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$. Then

$$V(S)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid y-2x=0\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid y=2x\}$$

and you see that $V(Y-2X)$ just represents the line $y=2x$ in the plane.

What happens if we have more than one polynomial? Then it becomes where your curves *intersect* in the plane.

So, let $S'=\{Y-2X,Y-4\}$. Then

$$V(S')=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid y-2x=y-4=0\}=\{(2,4)\}$$

where we get the point $(2,4)$ from solving the equation $y-2x=y-4=0$. This is representing the fact that $(2,4)$ is the only point of intersection of the two lines $y=2x$ and $y=4$.

Of course, this point is a subset of the set of solutions to $y=2x$, so in particular we see $V(S')\subset V(S)$.

Comment: You saved my day from frustration. Very nice explanation, thank you so much!

Comment: @kreide glad I could help!